# Python - Understanding Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, subprocess

So, I'm taking a list of usernames from a Linux server at school, this top code opens the directory where they are kept and saves it as information

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess, sys

r = subprocess.Popen(['ls','/home/ADILSTU'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
information = r.stdout.read()
print information, str(information)
```

that works just fine and list the users like this... where it list them 1 per line. (there is atleast 100 usernames)

```
ajax2
jjape3
jaxe32
```

my problem is, I want to create a "look-up" for these usernames, this is my code to search for usernames that only start with the letter j (so should only list jaxe32 from this list)

```
#lookup
import re
p = re.compile(r'j(?!j)\w*')
print p.match(str(information)).group()
```

but when I run this I get this error, and if I get rid of .group() it then just states "none", but no error. So i'm not sure if the list is getting saved to a string right, or if I'm just missing something obvious. I only want to use regular expression for this, not anything else.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "getInformation.py", line 11, in <module>
    print p.match(str(information)).group()
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: I mean to say starts with only one j not jj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match):

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object. Return None if the string does not match the pattern;

`re.match` is only useful if the match starts from the beginning of the string, it does not find all matches in a string.

This leaves you with two main options:

- Split the input file by line and use `re.match`
- Use multiline matching and `re.findall`

***Option 1***:

```
r = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '/home/administrator/sotest'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
information = r.stdout.read().decode('utf-8').split('\n') # ['ajax2', 'jaxe32', 'jjape3', '']

for user in information:
    s = re.match(r'j(?!j)\w*', user)
    if s:
        print(s.group())
```

Output:

```
jaxe32
```

***Option 2*** (using [`(?m)^j(?!j)\w*$`](https://regex101.com/r/FjRPvM/3/)):

```
r = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '/home/administrator/sotest'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
information = r.stdout.read().decode('utf-8') # 'ajax2\njaxe32\njjape3\n'

print(re.findall(r'(?m)^j(?!j)\w*$', information))
```

Output:

```
['jaxe32']
```

Comment: option 1 only printed out j's for each user that started with j but that was it so just got a bunch of j lines, but option 2 worked flawlessly, Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, option 1 works for me. Maybe your data is slightly different.  Glad option 2 works!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the `match` method doesn't match anything, it doesn't return an empty `match` object, on which you could call the `group` method, it returns `None`. Which does not have the `group` method. Just check for `None` before you call any methods.

```
#lookup
import re
p = re.compile(r'j(?!j)\w*')
result = p.match(str(information))
if result:
    print result.group()
```