# Upload '.xml' files to server using 'curl' in an Ansible playbook

Tags: curl, ansible

I am trying to upload multiple `.xml` files to a server and my Ansible playbook indicates the path isn't a directory, but the path and files are there.

For each `.xml` file I want to loop through and upload each one. The URI method doesn't work due to a known bug, so I reverted back to `curl`. The command works from the CLI without any problems.

Relevant Ansible `WARNING` message:

```
[WARNING]: Skipped '/tmp/oscap' path due to this access issue: '/tmp/oscap' is not a directory
```

I feel like I have refrigerator blindness and am missing something right in front of me. Help is greatly appreciated.

Added CLI output on paths and files for reference:

```
# ls -ld /tmp/oscap
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 42 Sep 17 22:28 /tmp/oscap 

# ls -l
total 16120 -rw-r--r--. 1 admin root 16504110 Sep 19 09:07 ans-01.corp.com.xml
```

```yaml
---
- name: Upload .xml files to server
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  
  vars:

    heimdall_hostname: 'http://heimdall.corp.com'
    heimdall_port: 42089
    evaluation_tags: scap
    api_key: >-
      eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJrZXlJZCI6IjMiLCJjcmVhdGVkQXQiOiIyMDIzLTA5LTIxVDIyOjQ2OjIyLjgyN1oiLCJpYXQiOjE2OTUzMzYzODJ9.RwmNVrpJ34Qm0JjiTU_JVYLDToldoAAajN4S5h-Afhg
    
  tasks:

  - name: Get a list of all the .xml files in the file path
    ansible.builtin.find:
      paths: /tmp/oscap
      file_type: file
      use_regex: yes
      patterns: '*.xml'
    register: xml_files

  - name: Upload each .xml file to the server
    ansible.builtin.shell:
      cmd: curl -k -F "data=@{{ item.path }}" \
          -F "filename={{ item.path | basename }}" \
          -F "public=false" -F "evaluationTags={{ evaluation_tags }}" \
          -H "Authorization:Api-Key {{ api_key }}" \
          "{{ heimdall_hostname }}:{{ heimdall_port }}/evaluations"
    loop: "{{ xml_files.files }}"
```

Everything is working except I am getting errors on hostname resolution. Here's the error output from the Ansible Controller.

```
failed: [ans-01.corp.com] (item={'path': '/tmp/oscap/ans-01.corp.com.xml', 'mode': '0644', 'isdir': False, 'ischr': False, 'isblk': False, 'isreg': True, 'isfifo': False, 'islnk': False, 'issock': False, 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 0, 'size': 16504110, 'inode': 2436, 'dev': 64774, 'nlink': 1, 'atime': 1695308203.6200945, 'mtime': 1695128852.3120863, 'ctime': 1695425843.6465063, 'gr_name': 'root', 'pw_name': 'admin', 'wusr': True, 'rusr': True, 'xusr': False, 'wgrp': False, 'rgrp': True, 'xgrp': False, 'woth': False, 'roth': True, 'xoth': False, 'isuid': False, 'isgid': False}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "curl -k -F \"data=@/tmp/oscap/ans-01.corp.com.xml\" \\ -F \"filename=ans-01.corp.com.xml\" \\ -F \"public=false\" -F \"evaluationTags=scap\" \\ -H \"Authorization:Api-Key eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJrZXlJZCI6IjMiLCJjcmVhdGVkQXQiOiIyMDIzLTA5LTIxVDIyOjQ2OjIyLjgyN1oiLCJpYXQiOjE2OTUzMzYzODJ9.RwmNVrpJ34Qm0JjiTU_JVYLDToldoAAajN4S5h-Afhg\" \\ \"http://heimdall.corp.com:42089/evaluations\"",
    "delta": "0:00:00.011430",
    "end": "2023-09-23 16:39:28.283482",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "curl -k -F \"data=@/tmp/oscap/ans-01.corp.com.xml\" \\ -F \"filename=ans-01.corp.com.xml\" \\ -F \"public=false\" -F \"evaluationTags=scap\" \\ -H \"Authorization:Api-Key eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJrZXlJZCI6IjMiLCJjcmVhdGVkQXQiOiIyMDIzLTA5LTIxVDIyOjQ2OjIyLjgyN1oiLCJpYXQiOjE2OTUzMzYzODJ9.RwmNVrpJ34Qm0JjiTU_JVYLDToldoAAajN4S5h-Afhg\" \\ \"http://heimdall.corp.com:42089/evaluations\"",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true
        }
    },
    "item": {
        "atime": 1695308203.6200945,
        "ctime": 1695425843.6465063,
        "dev": 64774,
        "gid": 0,
        "gr_name": "root",
        "inode": 2436,
        "isblk": false,
        "ischr": false,
        "isdir": false,
        "isfifo": false,
        "isgid": false,
        "islnk": false,
        "isreg": true,
        "issock": false,
        "isuid": false,
        "mode": "0644",
        "mtime": 1695128852.3120863,
        "nlink": 1,
        "path": "/tmp/oscap/ans-01.corp.com.xml",
        "pw_name": "admin",
        "rgrp": true,
        "roth": true,
        "rusr": true,
        "size": 16504110,
        "uid": 1000,
        "wgrp": false,
        "woth": false,
        "wusr": true,
        "xgrp": false,
        "xoth": false,
        "xusr": false
    },
    "msg": "non-zero return code",
    "rc": 3,
    "start": "2023-09-23 16:39:28.272052",
    "stderr": "curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL\n  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: filename=ans-01.corp.com.xml\ncurl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL\n  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current\n                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed\n\r  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: public=false\ncurl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL\ncurl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL\ncurl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL",
        "  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current",
        "                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed",
        "",
        "  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: filename=ans-01.corp.com.xml",
        "curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL",
        "  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current",
        "                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed",
        "",
        "  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: public=false",
        "curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL",
        "curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL",
        "curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL"
    ],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
ans-01.corp.com   : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Just to confirm what may seem obvious, can you include in your question the output of `ls -ld /tmp/oscap`?

Comment: Also, your `patterns` value is invalid. If you want to match files ending in `.xml`, you should have `patterns: [ '.*\.xml' ]`...or drop `use_regex: yes` and set patterns to `[  '*.xml' ]`.

Comment: "_The `URI` method doesn't work due to a known bug, so I reverted back to `curl`._", since I am interested in, do you have more information regarding it or a reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to reproduce a `[WARNING]` message and `Skipped` only if using [Parameter: `use_regex`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#parameter-use_regex) set to `true`.

> *If `false`, the patterns are file globs (shell).*
> *If `true`, they are python regexes.*
>
> *`false` <- default*

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - find:
      paths: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/test"
      patterns: '*.xml' # or '*.yml'
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.files | map(attribute='path') | list | map('basename') }}"
```

or even

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - find:
      paths: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/test"
      file_type: file
      patterns: '*.xml' # or '*.yml'
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.files | map(attribute='path') | list | map('basename') }}"
```

will result into just the filenames looking for.

---

If a (Python) Regular Expression is needed use in example

```yaml
  - find:
      paths: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/test"
      use_regex: true
      patterns: '^[a-z].*xml$' # or '^[a-z].*yml$'
    register: result
```

or as already mentioned within the comments `'.*\.xml'`.

**Further Documentation and Q&A**

- [Python - Understanding Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220129/)

  > *`re.match` is only useful if the match starts from the beginning of the string, it does not find all matches in a string.*
- and probably many more ...

Comment: Thank you U880D, that recommendation was enough to get me started troubleshooting, and I was able to resolve the remainder which turned out to be removing the double quotes and character returns in the curl command, since they were unnecessary.